# Token bucket consumption

Tags: probability

There is a bucket with tokens.
Initially, all the tokens in the bucket are old tokens.
Whenever someone picks up a token from the bucket, he replaces that token with a new token.
The rate of token consumption is R tokens per second.
After what time, 90% of the tokens in the bucket will be new tokens.

Comment: How many Tokens in the bucket? (Hopefully at least $R$)

Comment: One more thing I should mention, initially when someone picks up a token, that will be an old token since there are no new tokens. But after that, someone can pick up a new token as well. The person does not know what is new or old. But he will replace that with a new token. And R tokens per second does not mean the person will pick up all the R tokens at the same time, he will be doing it one by one, basically, the consumption rate is R tokens per second but that can be by multiple consumers, sumtotal will be R per second.

Comment: It still matters how many tokens there are at the start. If there is only one token, then we reach $100$% new tokens in $1/R$ second. But I think there are supposed to be more tokens.

Comment: Yes. It is at least greater than equal to R.

Comment: Just to clarify, when you say the user replaces the token, does that mean immediately (before the next token will be taken)? If users take tokens and replace them much later, it will change the time to reach $90$%.

Comment: He replaces it immediately. You can assume it happens in a transaction.

Comment: See how many unspoken assumptions there are in the original question statement. There are still others. Can we have a more precise statement, along with some information about how this question arises (e.g., computer science course) and what thoughts you have about how to approach it (such as, what do you already know that might be relevant).

Answer (score 2):

If there are $N$ tokens in the bucket and $M$ of them are new the next transaction increases the number of new ones with probability $\frac {N-M}N$, so the rate of expected increase is $\frac {N-M}NR$ per second.  This gives a differential equation $$\frac {dM}{dt}=\frac {N-M}NR\\M(0)=0$$ Can you solve that?

Comment: Just a question. I may be wrong, but wont the denominator be N as the total number of tokens in the bucket is N and the number of old tokens in the bucket is N-M, so (N-M)/N.

Comment: You are correct.  I have fixed it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is equivalent to the [coupon collector's problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem).  This problem asks for the expected number of trials it takes to collect some number $k$ of coupons out of a set of $n$ if you randomly draw one each trial.

To make the connection between the problems a little more clear, consider the following procedure:

- Lay out all $n$ coupons in a row.
- Each trial, select one at random.
- If you have not collected this one yet, mark it as collected.
- Once $k$ of the coupons have been marked, the test ends.

Now do the same thing with tokens:

- Lay out all $n$ tokens in a row.
- Each trial, select one at random.
- Replace it with a new token.
- Once $k$ of the tokens are new, the test ends.

The difference between the two is just the third step.  However, replacing the third step with "if the token is not new, replace it with a new token" is equivalent, since either way the token is new at the end of the step.

Now for the solution: the details are in the linked article, but here's the gist.  The number of old tokens will either remain the same, or decrease by one with each replacement.  The probability for an old token to be replaced when there are $i$ new tokens is just $\frac{n-i}{n}$, the number of old tokens over $n$.

Therefore the expected number of trials for the number of new tokens to increase from $i$ to $i+1$ is one over the probability, $\frac{n}{n-i}$.  Since expectations add linearly, we have the expected time for the number of new tokens to increase from $0$ to $k$ as:
$$
\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}\frac{n}{n-i}=n\left(H_{n}-H_{n-k-1}\right)\approx n\log\frac{n}{n-k-1}\approx -n\log f
$$
Where $f$ is the desired fraction of new tokens, equal to $\frac{n-k}{n}$.  You can compute the variance in a similar way, see the article for details.